# Keywords not recognised in Crystal Reports

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm attempting to recreate a form in Crystal Reports, under VS2010, after a form created under VS2008 stopped working.

I have reached a point where I am trying to copy the following function from the old form to the new:

```
Shared myVariable As String
myVariable = {myTable.myColumnName}
formula = ""
```

In the original function editor, the words "Shared" "As String" and "formula" are highlighted in blue as keywords.

In my new version of the report, only "Shared" is highlighted as a keyword. When I try and save the function, I am told it contains an error. This error is reported as:

```
"A variable type (for example, 'numberVar') is missing."
```

The formula works on the original formula workshop. Why not now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

There's a dropdown box at the top of the Formula Workshop, which was set to "Crystal Syntax". I changed it to "Basic Syntax" and everything was fine.

Leaving this question here in case anyone finds the same problem, because I couldn't get anything relevant out of google.

Answer (score 1):

```
shared stringVar myVariable;
myVariable = {myTable.myColumnName};
formula = ""
```

Above code works when Formula Workshop was set to "Crystal Syntax"